# Search for a city based off city id

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get cities which are equal to a particular city based off a user search I will be implementing .

I've got a sql query below which gives the exact output I want:

```
Select r.City, AVG(s.Longitude) AS Longitude, AVG(s.Latitude) AS Latitude
From CafeAddress r inner join Cafe s on s.CafeId = r.CafeId
Where City = 'Mumbai'
Group By City
```

Current output:

```
 City     Longitude  Latitude
Mumbai  -73.9904097  40.7036292
```

What I'm currently trying to add is a urlsafe "id" which is pretty much the city but with no white spaces, random chars just want it all lower case.

Like below:

```
 id        City     Longitude     Latitude
mumbai   Mumbai    -73.9904097   40.7036292
```

Is there a way to implement something like this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use a numeric id?

Comment: Other thought: Even in the UK alone we have Saint Ives in Cornwall, Cambridgeshire, and one in Dorset (although this one's a village and not a town). What's the plan for multiple places with the same name?

Comment: i guess I could create a region column as well to change this, is there another way to work around this?

Comment: If you want a stable id, create a new table and assign one. Or use a min(postcode) or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LOWER` to make it lowercase
Use `TRIM` to trim whitespace from beginning/end
Use `REPLACE` to replace interior spaces w/ underscore

```
Select REPLACE(TRIM(LOWER(r.City)),' ','_'),r.City, AVG(s.Longitude) AS Longitude, AVG(s.Latitude) AS Latitude
From CafeAddress r inner join Cafe s on s.CafeId = r.CafeId
Where City = 'Mumbai'
Group By City
```

Example, if r.City was '    SAN JOSE  '
it would return: `'san_jose'`

You can daisy chain `REPLACE()` to get rid of special characters or use [`TRANSLATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: SQL Server 2017 also add TRIM()

Comment: What about other white space and "random chars"?

Comment: is it missing some parenthesis??